# Função não reconhece variável global no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, escopo-de-variáveis

Quando eu uso variáveis para pode guardar conteúdo de caixas de texto, para pode executar em uma função(assim como está no código que deixei aqui), se as variáveis não estiverem dentro da função, o código não funciona corretamente. O código abaixo foi feito para capturar o conteúdo de uma caixa de texto number e mandar um alert com o que estava dentro da caixa, mas só funciona se eu colocar as variáveis dentro da função. Queria entender o porque já que a variável está no escopo global.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="num">

    <input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="clicar()">
    <script>
        var num = document.getElementById('num')
        var numero = Number(num.value)

        function clicar(){
            window.alert(numero)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que estranho, eu fiz um teste aqui e não deu problema algum. Se o seu código JavaScript for exatamente esse que você colocou na pergunta, será que você não esqueceu de chamar a função não ?

Comment: Acho que você deveria tentar **[edit]** a sua pergunta para adicionar o código como **texto**. Conforme pode ser lido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485), postar uma imagem como código não é uma boa prática nesse site, e a sua pergunta pode ser negativada por isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, há alguns motivos para isso, como veremos abaixo.

Um código é renderizado/interpretado de cima para baixo pelo navegador, portanto, se você faz, por exemplo, um código assim:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" onclick="clica()" id="texto"/>
  <body/>
</html>
```

E, no arquivo main.js, esteja:

```
var texto = document.getElementById('texto')
function clica(){  
   alert(texto)
}
```

Não vai funcionar como o esperado porque quando o interpretador passa pela primeira linha do código JavaScript, `var texto = document.getElementById('texto')`, o elemento HTML (input) ainda não foi renderizado, pois seu código HTML está abaixo do código JavaScript, assim a variável global recebe *undefined*, já que, nesse momento do código, como eu disse, o elemento HTML não foi renderizado, ou seja, **AINDA NÃO EXISTE**. A função reconhece a variável global normalmente, mas o conteúdo dela é *undefined*.

Para contornar esse problema, o mais comum é envolver a atribuição feita à variável global com a função *callback* chamada na hora clique no botão. Assim, a cada vez que o elemento for clicado (e a função, consequentemente, for chamada), a atribuição será feita.

Há ainda outro modo: colocar o código JavaScript, ou o *href* dele, abaixo, depois de todo o código HTML. Assim, o código JavaScript só será interpretado quando todos os elementos HTML tiverem sido renderizados pelo motor de renderização do navegador. No entanto, o problema dessa "abordagem" é que o valor não será atualizado a cada clique, já que o código JS fora de qualquer função só é interpretado uma vez.

Um exemplo desse modo de fazer é dado abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto">
    <button onclick="clicar()">clique em mim!</button>
    <script>
        var texto = window.document.getElementById('texto').value
        function clicar(){
            window.alert(texto)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Enfatizou bem o "não existe", hein. 

Comment: Desculpe por não ter colocado o código todo. Eu tentei editar algumas vezes o post para tentar por o código inteiro, mas só ia um pedaço. Agora que usei uma foto.

Comment: Tudo bem. Adicionei mais um código para facilitar a compreensão, consegue entender com essa explicação?

Comment: Eu entendi seu script, mas quando eu executo, se a sua variável "texto" não estiver dentro da função "clicar", sai apenas eu alert vazio. eu testei com a variável dentro da função e deu certo.

Comment: Justamente, e eu explico o porquê disso acontecer na minha resposta.

Comment: Está confusa a resposta. O problema não é ele pegar uma referência ao input no momento em que está pegando, isso funciona com o código da pergunta. O problema é pegar o value do elemento uma única vez, em vez de a cada clique.

Comment: Mas eu explico os dois casos: quando ele só pega uma vez e quando ele não pega (no caso de o elemento HTML não ter sido criado ainda)!!!!!

Comment: A metade de cima da resposta fala de uso de js externo, que não é o caso da pergunta. A metade de baixo inclui um exemplo com o mesmo problema do código da pergunta! Mesmo você explicando a questão do valor, na minha opinião continua confuso...

Comment: Bom, infelizmente se você não consegue interpretar bem, não posso fazer nada, a não ser aconselhar que passe a ler mais - e coisas variadas.

Comment: Eu estava tentando fazer uma crítica construtiva. Mas se você prefere dispensar a crítica me ofendendo, paciência.